# When i click the next or previous the thumbnail's are not changed

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, slider

its an image slider when I click the next I needs to change the image in the thumbnails  also but its not working. also not showing main picture when I click in the the first picture and the second is working but third also not working...

thumbnail's are not change through next and previous...
in slider images are change through next and previous but the thumbnails are not change with image...

Code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">


  <title></title>
  <style>
    .newsslider {
      width: 100%;
      height: 800px;
      background-color:#766582;
    }

    .text {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: white;
      margin-bottom: -101px;
    }

    .btn1,
    .btn2 {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: -30px;
      padding: 16px;
      color: #52492f;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }

    .btn2 {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    
    .btn1:hover,
    .btn2:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      color: white;
    }

    .onebtn {}

    .twobtn {}

    .thumbs {
      display: flex;
      padding-top: 6%;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .thumbs li {
      width: 12%;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1%;
    }

    .thumbs li img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .img12:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="newsslider">

    <p class="text" id="demo"><img id="demo1" src="img5.png" width=30%; height=400px;> </p>

    <div class="onebtn">
      <button id="btn1" class="btn1" type="button" class="prev" onclick="prev()">PREV</button>
    </div>

    <div class="twobtn">
      <button id="btn2" class="btn2" type="button" class="next" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
    </div>

    <p id="newsArr1" class="text" style="font-size:40px; font-weight:bolder; color: #521d2c;">Hi,</p>


    <ul class="thumbs">
      <li class="img12" onclick="thumbchange(1)"><img src="img5.png" width=500%;></li>
      <li class="img12" onclick="thumbchange(2)"><img src="img2.png"></li>
      <li class="img12" onclick="thumbchange(3)"><img src="img4.png"></li>
    </ul>

  </div>




  <script>
    var newsArr = ['<img src="img5.png"width = 30%; height=400px;>',
                   '<img src="img2.png"width = 30%; height=400px; >',
                  '<img src="img4.png" width = 30%; height=400px;>'];
    var newsArr1 = ["Hi",
                    "This is Urraan", 
                    "Urraan is a digital gateway"];
    var i = 0;
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    var y = document.getElementById("newsArr1");

    // var timeoutId;



    function next() {
      // if (timeoutId) {
      //   clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      // }
      i++;

      if (i < newsArr.length) {
        x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
        y.innerHTML = newsArr1[i];

      } else {
        i = 0;
        x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
        y.innerHTML = newsArr1[i];
      }
      // timeoutId = setTimeout(next, 2000);

    }



    function prev() {
      i--;
      if (i >= 0) {
        x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
        y.innerHTML = newsArr1[i];
      } else {
        i = newsArr.length - 1;

        x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
        y.innerHTML = newsArr1[i];

      }

    }

    function thumbchange(num) {
      var thumb = 'img' + num + '.png';
      document.getElementById("demo1").src = thumb;
    }
  </script>

</body>



</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you problem solved ... please try it.

```js
var newsArr = ['<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg"width = 100%; height=400px;>',
                   '<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg"width = 100%; height=400px; >',
                  '<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg" width = 100%; height=400px;>'];
    var newsArr1 = ["Hi",
                    "This is Urraan", 
                    "Urraan is a digital gateway"];
    var i = 0;
    var x = document.getElementById("demo");
    var y = document.getElementById("newsArr1");

    // var timeoutId;



    function next() {
      // if (timeoutId) {
      //   clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      // }
      i++;

      if (i < newsArr.length) {
        x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
        y.innerHTML = newsArr1[i];

      } else {
        i = 0;
        x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
        y.innerHTML = newsArr1[i];
      }
      // timeoutId = setTimeout(next, 2000);
      setThumbnailFocus(i)
    }



    function prev() {
      i--;
      if (i >= 0) {
        x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
        y.innerHTML = newsArr1[i];
      } else {
        i = newsArr.length - 1;

        x.innerHTML = newsArr[i];
        y.innerHTML = newsArr1[i];

      }
setThumbnailFocus(i)
    }

    function thumbchange(num) {
        x.innerHTML = newsArr[num-1];
        y.innerHTML = newsArr1[num-1];
        setThumbnailFocus(num-1)
    }
    function setThumbnailFocus(num){
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".thumbs .selected");

      [].forEach.call(elems, function(el) {
          el.classList.remove("selected");
      });
      document.getElementsByClassName("img12")[num].classList.add("selected");
    }
```

```css
.newsslider {
      width: 100%;
      height: 800px;
      background-color:#766582;
    }

    .text {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: white;
      margin-bottom: -101px;
    }

    .btn1,
    .btn2 {
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      width: auto;
      margin-top: -30px;
      padding: 16px;
      color: #52492f;
      font-weight: bold;
      font-size: 20px;
      border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
      user-select: none;
    }

    .btn2 {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
    }

    
    .btn1:hover,
    .btn2:hover {
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
      color: white;
    }

    .onebtn {}

    .twobtn {}

    .thumbs {
      display: flex;
      padding-top: 6%;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      list-style: none;
    }

    .thumbs li {
      width: 12%;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 1%;
    }

    .thumbs li img {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .img12:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 140, 186, 0.5);
    }
    .selected{
      border:solid 2px red
    }
```

```html
<div class="newsslider">

    <p class="text" id="demo"><img id="demo1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" width=100%; height=400px;> </p>

    <div class="onebtn">
      <button id="btn1" class="btn1" type="button" class="prev" onclick="prev()">PREV</button>
    </div>

    <div class="twobtn">
      <button id="btn2" class="btn2" type="button" class="next" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
    </div>

    <p id="newsArr1" class="text" style="font-size:40px; font-weight:bolder; color: #521d2c;">Hi,</p>


    <ul class="thumbs">
      <li class="img12 selected" onclick="thumbchange(1)"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/la.jpg" width=500%;></li>
      <li class="img12" onclick="thumbchange(2)"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/chicago.jpg"></li>
      <li class="img12" onclick="thumbchange(3)"><img src="https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/ny.jpg"></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
```

Comment: if you have bootstrap you can use bootstrap Carousel its very good and useful.

Comment: if my answer helps you please checked it as correct answer.

Comment: sir but when i canhge the picture its not focusing on thumbnails.. how can i do that

Comment: when cahnge  picture also change the thumbnails an dfocus on thumbnail..

Comment: yes sure ... I edit my code ... now it solved ... please check it.

Comment: sir working but not focus on thumbnails... i mean change image also changes thumnails and focus on thumnails that show the thumbnails also change..

Comment: Its worked for me ! in code snippet ... you cant see red border !?

Comment: thanks its working.... happy to do this i am stuck from 2 days. thanks alot

Comment: your welcome ... if every thing is ok please vote me and checked your question answered

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I found is that you have this code:

```
<p class="text" id="demo"><img id="demo1" src="img5.png" width=30%; height=400px;> </p>
```

And here you didn't use part with setting id:

```
var newsArr = ['<img //here is no id// src="img5.png"width = 30%; height=400px;>',
               '<img //here is no id// src="img2.png"width = 30%; height=400px; >',
              '<img //here is no id// src="img4.png" width = 30%; height=400px;>'];
```

And when you are clicking on next and prev button, you are removing your id unconsciously, so your thumbchange() function stop working, because it is based on id.